# How can you apply a Groovy trait with static methods to a Junit test class?

Tags: java, maven, groovy, junit

In a Maven-based Groovy project, I am using an embedded database with some of my JUnit test suites.

Because there is a non-trivial amount of setup needed for this embedded database, I decided to create a Groovy trait.  The trait would have `static` setup and teardown methods.  Thanks to the `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` annotations, any JUnit 5 class that implements this trait will call those methods once at the beginning and end of the suite.

```
trait EmbeddedDatabaseSupport {

   @BeforeAll
   static setup() {
      ...
   }

   @AfterAll
   static teardown() {
      ...
   }

}
```

```
class MyTest implements EmbeddedDatabaseSupport {

   @Test
   void testMethod() {
      ...
   }

}
```

When I run my test suite class directly in IntelliJ, it works just fine.

However, when I run all test suites with Maven (i.e. `./mvnw test`), I get compilation errors such as the following:

```
[ERROR] target/generated-sources/groovy-stubs/test/MyTest.java:[27,55] setup() in MyTest cannot implement setup() in EmbeddedDatabaseSupport
  overriding method is static
```

Any ideas why this might work directly through an IDE, but fail with Maven?  I am using version `1.8.1` of the `gmavenplus-plugin` for all of my Groovy compilation.

Comment: Might be worth checking what groovy / java versions you are using within your IDE, you could do this for example by adding some code like this: `println "groovy ${GroovySystem.version} - JVM: ${System.properties['java.version']}"` and then comparing them against the versions used by maven.

Comment: Looks to be Java 1.8 and Groovy 2.5.8 all around.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 possible explanations:

**The first one:**

Groovy traits are implemented in a way that they apply compile time transformations to the class that implements the trait.

As long as the implementing class is also a Groovy class there should not be a problem, however the compilation error says that that issue is in `MyTest.java` so it's a java class, therefor it should not work.

See [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912756/groovy-traits-in-java-classes) it looks to describe the similar situation.

I didn't check with the latest groovy versions though.

**An Another "theory":**

When you're using `gmavenplus` plugin it has a fairly big list of goals that should be judiciously configured. So it's possible that its configured wrong.
See [Here](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Usage#compiling-groovy-sources) for list of those goals and general explanation.